# MySql How to have many instances of a table to a column in another table

Tags: mysql

I am currently working on a school project abouth a restaurant app.
I have to make a multiple instances of a table "Products" to a column "Products_Id"
in table "Orders". Here are pictures of the two tables. How i am supposed to do
those tables?

Table Products

[image: Table Products]

Table Orders

[image: Table Orders]

Comment: Probably you have a confused idea in your mind. What do you mean for instance of a table? Do you mean an entry? What do you mean multiple instances of a table to a column? Do you mean a foreign key? Also, I don't understand the question since you already have the structure of the table.

Comment: Please post plain text, not images, so we can copy/paste them when answering.

Comment: You make multiple rows in `Orders`. Each row represents a particular product ordered by a specific table.

Comment: Are you referring to table Joins here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a "junction" or "lookup" table. They allow you to create a one-to-many relationship between your data. In your case, associating multiple products with a single order.

**Order Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Order(
id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY,
customer_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
location INT(10) NOT NULL
);
```

**Product Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product(
id INT(10) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
description VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
```

**Junction Table**

Each row would contain the `id` of the order, and the `id` of the product that was ordered. Then you would `JOIN` all the tables to get the data you need.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Order_to_Product(
id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY,
order_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
product_id INT(10) NOT NULL
);
```